# An explanation for syntax: 'let secretbox::Key(ref mut kb) = k;'

Tags: rust

I've been working with sodiumoxide to create a 'password manager' of sorts.
This particular example in the documentation has me stumped:

```
use sodiumoxide::crypto::secretbox;
use sodiumoxide::crypto::pwhash;

let passwd = b"Correct Horse Battery Staple";
let salt = pwhash::gen_salt();
let mut k = secretbox::Key([0; secretbox::KEYBYTES]);
{
    let secretbox::Key(ref mut kb) = k;
    pwhash::derive_key(kb, passwd, &salt,
                       pwhash::OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
                       pwhash::MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE).unwrap();
}
```

Specifically the line:

```
let secretbox::Key(ref mut kb) = k;
```

I don't quite understand the syntax of this or what it's doing. If someone could explain to me what is happening in this line that'd be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`secretbox::Key(ref mut kb)` is a [pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html). `secretbox::Key` is a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/structs.html#tuple-structs), so its fields are unnamed and surrounded by parentheses. `ref mut kb` binds `kb` to a mutable reference to the only field in the struct.

You could do the same with:

```
let kb = &mut k.0;
```